# Display Data one at a time using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display data one at a time but my code is displaying the data all at once, what am I missing ?
Here is my HTML/PHP CODE

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <?php for ($i=1; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
    ?>
    <p id="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="position: absolute; display:none; ">Name <?php echo $i; ?></p>
    <?php   
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript Code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count;
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        for(count = 0; count < 1000; count++){
            $("#"+count).show();
            setTimeout(function() { $("#"+count).hide(); }, 500);
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

I'm using jquery version 3.2.1

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: well, `setTimeout` doesn't pause javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this to show data one at a time.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("#"+(count++)).show();
        setTimeout(function() { $("#"+(count-1)).hide(); }, 500);
    });
});
</script>
```

One click to show all data one at a time with 500 ms delay:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        var iterator = function() {
            $("#"+(count++)).show();
            setTimeout(function() { $("#"+(count-1)).hide(); if (count<1000) iterator(); }, 500);
        }
        iterator();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the OP wants a single click to cause all of the data to be shown, one item after another with a delay between each.

Comment: This works but what I need is when I click it will show automatically and not triggered by clicking again the button

Comment: @nnnnnn yes what I need is one click and it will display the data one by one

Comment: @Martney Acha I added second part to do what you need, try it again.

Comment: @Val This works man !!! Thank you save a lot of time because of this!! Cheers !!!!

Comment: use `setInterval` as the process time between each setTimeout is not counted, like 500ms + 1ms + 500ms + 1ms, `setInterval` will just do 500ms + 500ms etc...

Comment: That is exactly what I've mentioned in my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jquery to append 1000 div inside a wrapper instead using PHP.

Ref my code if it's useful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    $(".wrapper").append("<div class='item' id='" + i + "'>" + i + "</div>");
  };
});
var step = 0;

function hideItemFunc() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $("#" + step).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
    step += 1;
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
  font-size: 9px;
  background: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn2" onclick="hideItemFunc()">Run</button>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey man, you have any idea if I would like to set 2 interval speed ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276591/append-div-with-interval-in-jquery @Minh

Comment: @MartneyAcha May I know your condition & the values of 02 inteval speed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval instead of setTimeout. That will call the function repeatedly. SetTimeout executes only once while setInterval is repetitive.

Also, the execution sequence you need repeated should inside the function body of setInterval.

```
var count = 1;
var delayMillis = 5000; //5 second

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                //your code to be executed after 5 second
                $("#" + count).show();
                count++;
            }, delayMillis);

        });
    });
```

The current code displays each of the p records after a 5 seconds one after another. anything else you need to do will be inside the setInterval Block